# Implement inclusion-exclusion efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

An am trying to implement [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) efficiently for the following values:

```
2/5, 2/5, 2/10, 2/10, 2/15, 2/15, ...
```

Of course, the program cannot run infinitely long, so I'd like to put a configurable limit on the number of terms.

For example, let's say I limit my calculation to:

```
2/5, 2/5, 2/10, 2/10
```

Then the calculation would be:

```
+ 2/5 + 2/5 + 2/10 + 2/10                  # choose 1 out of 4 terms
- 4/25 - 4/50 - 4/50 - 4/50 - 4/50 - 4/100 # choose 2 out of 4 terms
+ 8/250 + 8/250 + 8/500 + 8/500            # choose 3 out of 4 terms
- 16/2500                                  # choose 4 out of 4 terms
```

I find doing "choose x out of y" in an iterative manner to be a bit complicated.

Here is my current implementation:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext

getcontext().prec = 100

def getBits(num):
    bit = 0
    bits = []
    while num > 0:
        if num & 1:
            bits.append(bit)
        bit += 1
        num >>= 1
    return bits

def prod(arr):
    res = Decimal(1)
    for val in arr:
        res *= val
    return res

SIZE = 20
sums = [Decimal(0) for k in range(SIZE)]
temp = [Decimal(2)/(5*k) for k in range(1,SIZE)]
probabilities = [p for pair in zip(temp,temp) for p in pair][:SIZE]

for n in range(1,1<<SIZE):
    bits = getBits(n)
    sums[len(bits)-1] += prod([probabilities[bit] for bit in bits])

total = 0
for k in range(SIZE):
    total += sums[k]*(-1)**k
print(total)
```

As you can see, I do the "choose x out of y terms" by generating every possible bit-combination between `1` and `2 ** SIZE`, and then choosing the terms in the `probabilities` array which are located in the positions which are marked `1` in the current bit-combination.

I am essentially looking for a more efficient way to do this, as the number of iterations grows exponentially by the value of `SIZE`.

I am aware of the fact that it might not be feasible, because the total number of terms in the inclusion-exclusion expression is technically exponential (the sum of a row in Pascal triangle).

However, since the values in `probabilities` are all known and "nice" (i.e., a power of 2 divided by a product of 5), I've figured that there is possibly a "shortcut" here which I have overlooked.

Comment: sorry, could you explain what inclusion exclusion is, or where those numbers come from? I feel like im missing some context here.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Added a link, thank you.

Comment: @goodvibration Could you - it would be even better - include the relevant parts of the explanation in the question itself?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: Is the numeric example at the top of my question not clear enough to explain it? The deep explanation on Wikipedia is actually a lot more complicated to understand IMO. I can point to a specific section in that description, which gives a numeric example too, but that one is more or less the same as what I wrote here.